Pen drive stops working after using it on xbox | series s
After I use my ScanDisk 64gb thumbstick on my Xbox|Series S to view media, the usb-drive malfunctions and I cant open it on my ubuntu. However, when I put the thumbstick back on the xbox it works normally.
I have to format the usb-drive again for it to be usable on my ubuntu.
Does anybody knows what the problem might be?

This link may help you solve and in the future avoid the problems. If still problems, you can analyze the problem according to this link and if you are lucky, find a solution.

On Ubuntu, with the flash drive plugged in, try running ntfsfix. man ntfsfix, for options.
